Find case-insensitive substring in array of objects within array of objects in JavaScript
I'm not sure how to deal with nested arrays and objects in JavaScript. I need to check if any of the Titles - whether the main folder Title or the Title within Contents - include a certain case-insensitive word (information in the sample code). It can stop checking as soon as it finds the word in any Title. I need to skip over/ignore the Description.


const data = [{
    "Title": "folder title 1",
    "Id": 857412,
    "Description": { "Text": "description 1" },
    "Contents": [
        { "Title": "contents 1 title 1", "Id": 123456 },
        { "Title": "contents 1 title 2 - Information", "Id": 987654 }
    ]
},{
    "Title": "folder title 2",
    "Id": 895623,
    "Description": { "Text": "description 2" },
    "Contents": [
        { "Title": "contents 2 title 3", "Id": 784512 }
    ]
}];

const contents = data.map(item => ({Contents:item.Contents}));
const folders = data.map(item => ({Title:item.Title}));
const combinedData = contents.concat(folders);
const stringData = JSON.stringify(combinedData);
console.log(stringData.toLowerCase().includes("information"));



My code works but I'm 100% sure that there is a better way to do this and I'm not sure how much data I'll be dealing with each time. I just cannot wrap my head around the array of objects within an array of objects and I'm still too new to JavaScript to understand many methods. The examples on websites are too simplistic with just a few numbers in an array, which doesn't help with this data.
What is a better method to use? How can I check the Titles for both folders and contents at the same time, while also ignoring Description, without needing to concatenate and stringify in order to find the word? Thanks for any suggestions!

What is your metric for "better"? How can I measure if one method is better than another?

@RokoC.Buljan What's wrong with JSON.stringify? If it solves the problem and is faster than other solutions, why not?

@RokoC.Buljan There is a .map. The keys are removed. The OP wrote, the code works correctly

@RokoC.Buljan That's 22 lines of code (5 lines without data). How could you miss anything? I assume, you wrote the comment without reading the code.

Really missed it, was too focused on that stringify and thought that, yes, the entire thing was being stringified - and read from. And moved on to read Barmar's answer. My bad

Don't concatenate everything, just use Array.some() to search the arrays for a matching title in the top-level array or the nested Contents arrays. This will stop as soon as it finds a match.


function titlesIncludes(data, search) {
  search = search.toLowerCase();
  return data.some(item =>
    item.Title.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
    item.Contents.some(content => content.Title.toLowerCase().includes(search)));
}

console.log(titlesIncludes(data, "information"));
console.log(titlesIncludes(data, "nothing"));
<script>
  const data = [{
    "Title": "folder title 1",
    "Id": 857412,
    "Description": {
      "Text": "description 1"
    },
    "Contents": [{
        "Title": "contents 1 title 1",
        "Id": 123456
      },
      {
        "Title": "contents 1 title 2 - Information",
        "Id": 987654
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "Title": "folder title 2",
    "Id": 895623,
    "Description": {
      "Text": "description 2"
    },
    "Contents": [{
      "Title": "contents 2 title 3",
      "Id": 784512
    }]
  }];
</script>




Barmar's nice answer specifically solves your question —
speaking of folders having contents we could be easily speaking about Tree Nodes.
Besides files, a folder's Contents could also easily have sub-folders and so on, therefore here's my two cents:
create a recursive function that checks for deeply nested nodes
/** Get Contents' node by key value; case-insensitive */
const getNode = (arr = [], prop = "", val = "") => {
  for (const node of arr) {
    if (node[prop].toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase())) return node;
    const res = getNode(node.Contents, prop, val);
    if (res) return res;
  }
};

// Use like:
console.log(getNode(data, "Title", "information"));
// Or like:
if (getNode(data, "Title", "information")) { console.log("found"); };

This way you can have as many nested Contents nodes as you want.
As in this example:


const data = [{
    "Title": "folder title 1",
    "Id": 857412,
    "Description": {
      "Text": "description 1"
    },
    "Contents": [{
        "Title": "contents 1 title 1",
        "Id": 123456
      },
      {
        "Title": "contents 1 title 2",
        "Id": 987654
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Title": "folder title 2",
    "Id": 895623,
    "Description": {
      "Text": "description 2"
    },
    "Contents": [{
      "Title": "contents 2 title 3",
      "Id": 784512
    }, {
      "Title": "SUBFOLDER",
      "Id": 999999,
      "Contents": [{
        "Title": "contents 3 title 3 - Information",
        "Id": 987654
      }]
    }]
  }
];

/** Get Contents' node by key value; case-insensitive */
const getNode = (arr = [], prop = "", val = "") => {
  for (const node of arr) {
    if (node[prop].toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase())) return node;
    const res = getNode(node.Contents, prop, val);
    if (res) return res;
  }
};

console.log(getNode(data, "Title", "information"));
if (getNode(data, "Title", "information")) {
  console.log("found");
};




Thank you, I learned something today....
